# PHP cURL send bool POST variable

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

I'm having PHP curl script that send some POST variables to CloudFlare API:
My fields are:

```
    $fields = array(
        'type' => 'A',
        'name' => $subdomain.rand(1, 2000),
        'content' => Env::getCFIP(),
        'proxied' => true,
        'ttl' => 1
    );
```

And the curl **curl_setopt** are:

```
        array(
            CURLOPT_POST            => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $fields,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 3,
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 0,
            CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE    => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
                'X-Auth-Email: '.Env::getCFEmail(),
                'X-Auth-Key: '.Env::getCFAuthKey(),
            )
        );
```

Default is value of **'proxied'** is false. If I skip it in data fields, scripts works. However, I want to have it on true, but I get error:

```
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'success' => boolean false
      public 'errors' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[8]
              public 'code' => int 1004
              public 'message' => string 'DNS Validation Error' (length=20)
              public 'error_chain' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    object(stdClass)[7]
                       public 'code' => int 9003
                       public 'message' => string 'Invalid 'proxied' value, must be a boolean' (length=42)
      public 'messages' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'result' => null
```

So my guess is that when cURL send POST request it converts data variables to STRING. Is there any way to stop this behavior?

Comment: you can send 1 for true, and 0 for false for this.

Comment: @tanaydin , setting it up as 1, '1', 'true', 'True', does not work.

Comment: when you get back, convert it to integer and it could work.

Comment: @tanaydin casting it to bool, int, or casting $fields array as object do not work. I still got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I manage to solve that one by:

1. Encoding fields as **json**:

   ```
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => json_encode($fields),
   ```
2. Adding **'Content-Type: application/json'** in headers

   ```
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER      => array(
           'X-Auth-Email: '.Env::getCFEmail(),
           'X-Auth-Key: '.Env::getCFAuthKey(),
           'Content-Type: application/json',
   ```

Comment: I was going to say, payloads via cURL are normally JSON or XML format, depending on the API endpoint.